# Netcat exits on UDP response

Tags: networking, network-programming, udp, netcat

Could you explain the "weird" behaviour?
I'm running netcat on Linux, as a UDP echo server:

```
ncat -4 --exec /bin/cat -u --listen 2000
```

Next, run client:

```
$ ncat -s 192.168.1.2 -u 127.0.0.1 2000
```

Machine has a real network adapter with the address: 192.168.1.2.
After I typed something, the server just exited:

```
$ ncat -4 --exec /bin/cat -u --listen 2000 ; x=$?; echo $x                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
0
```

Why?

[image: Wireshark]

Comment: It does work using tcp, I would ask the question on their git issue tracker: https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues

Comment: No, it works over UDP. In Wireshark I can see that `ncat` receives the client's request and then sends back the response. But the response was not delivered to the client. Another example: I have written a simple UDP server and using `netcat` as a client. The situation repeats (but the server, of course, is still alive).

Comment: Running  `strace` on server you can see it recieved the request and then failed with error `connection refused`. `ncat -s 192.168.1.2 -u 0.0.0.0 2000` is working , and the original command with tcp client and server is also working. This `ncat -s 192.168.1.2 -u 192.168.1.2 2000` will probably also work. I think your request should also work and it might be a bug in ncat itself.

Comment: Yes, if it's "connection", it's a TCP, possibly. But, first, why don't I see any 'SYN', 'ACK', etc. in the Wireshark? Just ICMP: "Destination (port) unreachable".
Moreover, if I pass the interface address (`ncat -s 192.168.1.2 -u 192.168.1.2 2000`), it works. Look at the picture, I've added (interface adress - 192.168.2.13).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `ncat` limitation.

Let's use `strace` to look into what `ncat` is up to. Conveniently, `strace` has `-e` option to filter system calls, e.g. `-e %net` for logging network-related syscalls. Let's start the server first:

```
$ strace -e %net ncat -4 --exec /bin/cat -u --listen 2000
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2000), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
```

Note the `bind` call. The socket is bound to 0.0.0.0, meaning that it will receive packets sent to 127.0.0.1:2000 as well as 10.0.2.15:2000 (my `eth0` address), as well as any other address belonging to the machine.

Now let's start a client:

```
$ strace -e %net  ncat -s 10.0.2.15 -u 127.0.0.1 2000
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.2.15")}, 16) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, [1], 4) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(2000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
getsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
```

At this point, the client is waiting for input.

Notice the `connect` call. UDP is connectionless, so the call simply remembers the remote's address. It is convenient as `send` will use the recorded address. Otherwise, it would be necessary to specify the remote address in every `send` call. *There's another implication which we'll see shortly.*

Now let's type some input. Client:

```
sendto(3, "Hello, world!\n", 14, 0, NULL, 0) = 14
```

Server:

```
recvfrom(3, "Hello, world!\n", 131072, MSG_PEEK, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(35197), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.2.15")}, [128->16]) = 14
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(35197), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.2.15")}, 16) = 0
recvfrom(3, "Hello, world!\n", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 14
sendto(3, "Hello, world!\n", 14, 0, NULL, 0) = 14
recvfrom(3, 0x7fff8fcc9d70, 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The server sees a message from 10.0.2.15. The first `recvfrom` call is done with `MSG_PEEK` flag, which allows to peek at the message without actually consuming it. Then `connect` (for convenience), another `recvfrom` to consume the message, and `sendto` to send a reply.

Now remember that the server socket is bound to 0.0.0.0. The client sent a message to 127.0.0.1:2000. The reply must include the server socket's address as the source. But the system can't use 0.0.0.0 as it doesn't generally make sense on the wire. Both 127.0.0.1 and 10.0.2.15 are possible, but `ncat` doesn't tell explicitly which one to use. So the system ends up using 10.0.2.15 as the source.

Now back to the client. It sent a message to 127.0.0.1:2000, but the response came from 10.0.2.15:2000. Another effect of `connect` on a UDP socket is that only datagrams originating from the specified address:port will be accepted. If the source doesn't match, the system responds with *ICMP port unreachable*. This is reported as `ECONNREFUSED` error in the server.

#### Possible fix

Specify the intended source address in the server using `IP_PKTINFO`/`IPV6_PKTINFO` ancillary message.

Comment: It does work with tcp , so it's kind of incosistent IMO

Comment: But, it seems to be true. TCP `connect` is not UDP "`connect`", TCP creates a channel and use more complicated mechanisms.
But...

Comment: It's funny, but I have two netcat versions: `ncat` and `nc`. This trick works only with `ncat`, which used `sendto`/`recvfrom` syscalls. `nc` using `connect` and `send`/`recv` (`write`/`read` syscalls`) works.

Comment: It works, but `connect` is used: https://pastebin.com/dHhM0Y83
@Nick Zavaritsky , why does it work?

Comment: @A.N. pay close attention to lines 1,2,5,6 in the trace. Server socket has IP_PKTINFO enabled, so in line 1 we find out that the client was talking to 127.0.0.1. Then a secondary socket is created and bound to 127.0.0.1 (2,5) and used for communiction so that the response comes from the proper IP.

Comment: Yes, I see this now. Definitely, you're right. Possibly, this implementation of netcat is newer and more correct. The problem was not very clear to understand. Thank you for the answer.